# How to change styles-m.css in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, css

Can any one tell me how can i change my theme css present in /pub/static/version1573734125/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkickchristmas/en_US/css/styles-m.css.

As we cant change anything in pub/static, is there any way we can override this file or anything such that to modify css present here.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite this file add it to your theme - `app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/web/css/styles-m.less`

Comment: sorry this does not work. still old css are getting applied.